# Umbraco API Controllers - Resolve From DI Container

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac, umbraco7

I'm trying to get Umbraco to play nicely with Autofac so that my API controllers are resolved through the container and I can add constructor dependencies.

Whenever I try to access an API controller at the moment, I get an error from the default controller activator:

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type
>   'MigrateUsersController'. Make sure that the controller has a
>   parameterless public constructor.

But I don't want to use the default activator - I want the controllers resolved from Autofac. This is what I have atm:

```
public static void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    //register all controllers found in this assembly
    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(IocConfig).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(IocConfig).Assembly);

    builder.RegisterControllers(typeof(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication).Assembly);
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(typeof(Umbraco.Web.UmbracoApplication).Assembly);

    builder.RegisterModule(new ServiceRegistrar());

    container = builder.Build();
    app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
}
```

Anyone know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer here:
http://24days.in/umbraco-cms/2015/integrating-an-application-into-umbraco-(using-ninject)/

I was missing this:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), new UmbracoWebApiHttpControllerActivator(kernel));
```

And here's my implementation of the custom activator:

```
public class UmbracoWebApiControllerActivator : IHttpControllerActivator
{
    private readonly DefaultHttpControllerActivator _defaultHttpControllerActivator;
    private readonly IContainer _container;

    public UmbracoWebApiControllerActivator(IContainer container)
    {
        this._defaultHttpControllerActivator = new DefaultHttpControllerActivator();
        this._container = container;
    }

    public IHttpController Create(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, Type controllerType)
    {
        object instance = null;
        if (_container.TryResolve(controllerType, out instance))
        {
            if (instance is IHttpController)
                return (IHttpController)instance;
        }

        IHttpController controller  =
            this.IsUmbracoController(controllerType)
                ? Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType) as IHttpController
                : this._defaultHttpControllerActivator.Create(request, controllerDescriptor, controllerType);

        return controller;
    }

    private bool IsUmbracoController(Type controllerType)
    {
        return controllerType.Namespace != null
            && controllerType.Namespace.StartsWith("umbraco", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```